# File get content not working in php

Tags: php

I am using the following code to retrieve my gmail inbox with PHP, but the code is not working. What am I doing wrong ?

```
$urls = "https://mygmail@gmail.com:mypassword@gmail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/";
$fileContents = file_get_contents($urls);

print_R($fileContents);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your PHP configuration, this may be a easy as using:

```
$urls="https://mygmail@gmail.com:mypassword@gmail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/";
$fileContents = file_get_contents($urls);
```

> However, if allow_url_fopen isn't enabled on your system, you could
>   read the data via CURL as follows:

```
<?php
    $ch= curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urls);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($curlSession);
    echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: @Quynh Nguyen: with my code, its displaying following error 

" 404. That’s an error.

The requested URL /mail/feed/atom/ was not found on this server. That’s all we know. SimpleXMLElement Object ( )"

Comment: You can pass curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); but dont try to use curl request or file_get_contents with google... buble boat is very smart and if you try much then your ip will be blocked.